# Offered a bounty and deleted account

Tags: support, bounties

Yesterday I offered a bounty on question:

[Can an atom have more than 8 valence electrons? If not, why is 8 the limit?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/444/can-an-atom-have-more-than-8-valence-electrons-if-not-why-is-8-the-limit)

to reward an existing answer. But as I was not very active on the site, nor do I like the subject, **I forgot about the bounty and deleted my Chemistry.SE account** this morning, before the bounty was 24hrs old (had not award it till then).

Who'll get the bounty?

The bounty is currently owned by **Community ♦** which seems to like [a background process and not a real person](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). So I can't ask it to award the bounty to someone particular.

Comment: See in the duplicate, under what is automatic awarding.

Comment: @Oded: But this post is completely answered from all aspects and no-one will ever post a new answer.So the bounty gets wasted?

Comment: @exploringnet: it's not wasted. It gives that question more visibility, so the answers will probably get voted on a bit more than if you hadn't posted that bounty.